# SQL server cursor inside of cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

0I'm having a problem with cursor inside of cursor logic, but looking my problem I do not see any other logical solution. What I'm trying to do is: Table given i n this form:

```
CollID   Coll_Value  Account     Dept
```

 
 181     1,000,000  500000251    500,000 
 181     1,000,000  500000252    100,000 
 181     1,000,000  500000253    90,000 
 184     10,000     500000251    500,000
 185     10,000     500000254    50,000 
 185     10,000     500000255    50,000

I need to make collateral cover as much dept as possible with 150%.
Criteria is to cover the largest dept first.

So the result should be:

```
Account    Dept       Divided collateral 
500000251   500,000    500,000*1,5= 750,000(the biggest expose first)
500000252   100,000    100,000*1,5 = 150,000
500000253   90,000     1,000,000-750,000-150,000 (it dosn't cover-the rest goes here)
500000254   50,000     10,000
500000255   50,000     0
```

Now what I wanna know is the cursor inside of cursor the way I should approach my problem? Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Can you please post some code? Also, what SQL server and client system are you on?

Comment: Check the data in the top table - you have two records with collID 185 but different Coll_Value. It isn't clear how you are apportioning the collateral.  You should probably normalise this data - one table defining collaterals, another for departments, maybe another for accounts and then one or more tables that link them together.  Show us the query that joins them and then we may be able to provide a solution.

Comment: @gwaigh, the problem lies in the fact that the entries repeat, one value for collateral corresponds to multiple value of dept, also one dept can be covered by multiple collaterals. So the logic is to fix one collateral ID and then look all account that he has with him, pick the biggest dept and look if dept*150%<collateral if yes then write it in a new column and subtract that amount out of collateral and then look if the second_dept*150%<reminder if yes write in a now column dept*150% else write reminder.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.